# jQuery: Click event detected many times

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery click event handling.

Here's my code:

```
$j("#btn_renommer_groupe").click(function(){
  document.forms['creation_edition_groupe'].reset();
  $j("#img_saisie_nom_groupe").hide();
  $j("input[name=creation_groupe]").css("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
  fun_renommer_groupe();
})

function fun_renommer_groupe(){
  alert('test');
}
```

The problem is, when I click on the button the alert message is display many time.

does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

EDIT:

Thx for your response. I can't post all the js file (more than 1000 lines) but Here are two unique operations that I do on this button

```
$j("#btn_renommer_groupe").unbind('click');
```

and

```
$j("#btn_renommer_groupe").bind('click', function(){fun_renommer_groupe();});
```

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: I don't believe you. Where do you bind this click event in? Show us full javascript please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you're binding click event to the same control way too many times.

this

```
$j("#btn_renommer_groupe").click(function(){
  ...
  fun_renommer_groupe();
})
```

and this

```
$j("#btn_renommer_groupe").bind('click', function(){fun_renommer_groupe();});
```

will result in `fun_renommer_groupe()` called twice on btn_renommer_groupe click event, see what I mean in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DpCDh/

**Make sure you only bind it once and you're sorted!**

Comment: Thx for your response. I think it's that too. I've tried with the "one" event but nothing change. I've a lot of "bind" in my code. I think I'll watch my code from the beginning. I replaced the buttons with images. They have no attribute "disable", so I used "bind" and "unbind", is there a better solution?

Comment: what do you unbind click events for? if you disable a button, click event won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

the code seems correct... except for the curious **$j** (why you are not using simply $() or jQuery()? :P)

If you are not looping somewhere... ensure you are not importing twice your script!

Comment: I use the jquery_no_conflict.js script. I can mixed Prototype with $ and jQuery with $j